Macros Error with copy and paste information on Excel
I have the following problem:
I have a file named "Template_National_Lookahead" where I have a table on Sheet1 as following



NAME
DATA 1
DATA 2
DATA 3




Name 1






11
data1 name1
40



12
data2 name1
30



13
data3 name1
40



14
data4 name1
10



Subtotal




Name 2






21
data1 name2
40



22
data2 name2
30



23
data3 name2
40



Subtotal




Name 3






31
data1 name3
40



32
data2 name3
30



33
data3 name3
40



34
data4 name3
30



35
data5 name3
40



I need to put the information in another Excel named "Book1" where I have, almost, the same structure but the names are mixed.
I tried using this code:
Sub CopiarInformacionDependiendoDelNombre()

    Dim archivoA As Workbook
    Dim archivoB As Workbook
    Dim hojaA As Worksheet
    Dim hojaB As Worksheet
    Dim nombre As String
    Dim celdaA As Range
    Dim celdaB As Range
    Dim ultimaFilaA As Long
    Dim rangoDatos As Range
    Dim filaSubtotalA As Long
    
    Set archivoA = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\JL\Desktop\TEST\Template_National_Lookahead.xlsm")
    Set archivoB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\JL\Desktop\TEST\Book1.xlsm")

    Set hojaA = archivoA.Sheets(1)
    Set hojaB = archivoB.Sheets(1)

    For Each celdaB In hojaB.Range("P2:P" & hojaB.Cells(hojaB.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row)
        
        nombre = celdaB.Value
        
        Set celdaA = hojaA.Range("B2:B" & hojaA.Cells(hojaA.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Find(nombre, LookIn:=xlValues)
        
        If Not celdaA Is Nothing Then
            filaSubtotalA = hojaA.Range(celdaA.Offset(1, 1), hojaA.Cells(hojaA.Rows.Count, celdaA.Column + 1)).Find("Subtotal", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
            
            Set rangoDatos = hojaA.Range(celdaA.Offset(1, 1), hojaA.Cells(filaSubtotalA - 1, celdaA.Column + 2))
            
            rangoDatos.Copy
            
            Set celdaB = hojaB.Range("P2:P" & hojaB.Cells(hojaB.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row).Find(nombre, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not celdaB Is Nothing Then
                celdaB.Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
        End If
        
    Next celdaB

    archivoB.Save
    archivoA.Save

    MsgBox "Proceso completado", vbInformation

End Sub

But, as result I have



NAME
DATA 1
DATA 2




Name 1















11
data1 name1



12
data2 name1


Name 2
13
data3 name1



14
data4 name1



22
data2 name2



23
data3 name2


Name 3





31
data1 name3



32
data2 name3



33
data3 name3



34
data4 name3



35
data5 name3



Also, the program paste the row with number Data 1: 11, 12, 13, 14 in the same cell everytime. I mean, they paste the name 2, and then paste de previus data again in the same place, then paste the info of name 3 and then, again, paste de preovius data again in the same place.
I will be glad if someone could help finding the problem.
Thanks to everyone.

I would suggest using Power Query to solve the problem you have created by using VBA.

I can't use it because the "Book1" file is in a online folder, shared with the company and could be modified. I'm trying to do something more automatically because I need to copy and paste every name (almost 35). I already did some test to handle both files, and It worked, but that is the only error I have.

It's not clear what the destination sheet looks like before you run your code, and there are no column letters in your sample data to help us match the code to the input/output.

Assume that on the target sheet



Row
Column P




2
Name 1


3
Name 2


4
Name 3



Add the missing Subtotal into the bottom of the source table for Name 3 since you look for it.
Instead of PasteSpecial which not insert rows in the table and it is unknown how long a NAME actually is, I used the Insert method.
Sub CopiarInformacionDependiendoDelNombre()

    Dim archivoA As Workbook
    Dim archivoB As Workbook
    Dim hojaA As Worksheet
    Dim hojaB As Worksheet
    Dim nombre As String
    Dim celdaA As Range
    Dim celdaB As Range
    Dim ultimaFilaA As Long
    Dim rangoDatos As Range
    Dim filaSubtotalA As Long
    
    Set archivoA =Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\JL\Desktop\TEST\Template_National_Lookahead.xlsm")
    Set archivoB =Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\JL\Desktop\TEST\Book1.xlsm")

    Set hojaA = archivoA.Sheets(1)
    Set hojaB = archivoB.Sheets(1)

    For Each celdaB In hojaB.Range("P2:P" & hojaB.Cells(hojaB.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row)
    If celdaB <> "" Then
        nombre = celdaB.Value
        
        Set celdaA = hojaA.Range("B2:B" & hojaA.Cells(hojaA.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Find(nombre, LookIn:=xlValues)
        
        If Not celdaA Is Nothing Then
            filaSubtotalA = hojaA.Range(celdaA.Offset(1, 1), hojaA.Cells(hojaA.Rows.Count, celdaA.Column + 1)).Find("Subtotal", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
            
            Set rangoDatos = hojaA.Range(celdaA.Offset(1, 1), hojaA.Cells(filaSubtotalA - 1, celdaA.Column + 2))
            
            
            Set celdaB = hojaB.Range("P2:P" & hojaB.Cells(hojaB.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row).Find(nombre, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not celdaB Is Nothing Then
                celdaB.Offset(1).Resize(rangoDatos.Rows.Count).Insert xlShiftDown
                rangoDatos.Copy
                celdaB.Offset(1, 1).Insert xlShiftDown
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Next celdaB

    archivoB.Save
    archivoA.Save

    MsgBox "Proceso completado", vbInformation

End Sub


This is the before/after of the target sheet.

